# Resize SVG contents based on the result of rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I thought this would be obvious and I must be missing something, but take this very simple code

```
<svg style="width:1000px;height:600px;border:1px solid red">
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    <text x="50" y="15" fill="red" text-anchor="end">A very long string A very long string A very long string</text>
</svg>
```

The text goes off to the left and gets chopped because its effective coordinates go negative.

I want to rescale and rezoom my SVG contents so that, after rendering, everything is visible and the leftmost content is on the left boundary and the rightmost content is on the right boundary, same with top and bottom.

I'm using d3 so anything in there that achieves this end goal would be good also.

```
ensureEverythingIsVisible="1"  // would be great :--)
```

```html
<svg style="width:1000px;height:600px;border:1px solid red">
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    <text x="50" y="15" fill="red" text-anchor="end">A very long string A very long string A very long string</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found a way using javascript. I hadn't looked into getBBox much and that is the solution:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var svgnode = svg.node();
var bbox = svgnode.getBBox();
svg.attr("viewBox", bbox.x + " " + bbox.y + " " + bbox.width + " " + bbox.height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg style="width:1000px;height:600px;border:1px solid red">
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    <text x="50" y="15" fill="red" text-anchor="end">A very long string A very long string A very long string</text>
</svg>
```